# Patch udpates and Validate RequestBody

Tags: java, hibernate, api, jpa

I have been studying spring boot for a few weeks.
I am building a simple api using hibernate + jpa with a mysql database.

I have a resource call TvShowReminderResponseDTO  :

```
public class TvShowReminderResponseDTO {
    // Attributes
    private Integer idTvShowReminder;
    private User user;
    private UserTvShow userTvShow;
    private TvShowDetailsResponseDTO tvShowDetailsResponseDTO;
    private Boolean completed;
    private Integer currentSeason;
    private Integer currentEpisode;
    private Integer personalRating;
    
    // rest of the code omittedfor brevity
}
```

In my controller i have a basic update PATCH endpoint, that receives the id of the tv show reminder (entity) that is stored in my database and also i receive a TvShowReminderPatchDTO with the information i want to update:

PatchDTO and Controller:

```
public class TvShowReminderPatchDTO {
    // Attributes
    private Optional<Boolean> completed;
    private Optional<Integer> currentSeason;
    private Optional<Integer> currentEpisode;
    private Optional<Integer> personalRating;
    // rest of the code omittedfor brevity
}

    @PatchMapping("/{idTvShowReminder}")
    public void updateTvShowReminder(@RequestBody @Valid TvShowReminderPatchDTO tvShowReminderToUpdate, 
    @PathVariable  Integer idTvShowReminder){
        tvShowReminderService.updateTvShowReminder(tvShowReminderToUpdate,idTvShowReminder);
    }
```

Also I have my service method that is in charge of searching the TvShowReminder entity by its id, and then update the information we get from the client.

```
public void updateTvShowReminder(TvShowReminderPatchDTO tvShowReminderToUpdate, Integer idTvShowReminder) {
        Optional<TvShowReminder> tvShowReminder = getTvShowReminder(idTvShowReminder);
        TvShowReminder currentTvShowReminder = tvShowReminder.get();

        if(tvShowReminderToUpdate.getCompleted() != null) {
            if (tvShowReminderToUpdate.getCompleted().isPresent()) {
                currentTvShowReminder.setCompleted(tvShowReminderToUpdate.getCompleted().get());
            } else {
                currentTvShowReminder.setCompleted(null);
            }
        }

        if(tvShowReminderToUpdate.getCurrentSeason() != null) {
            if (tvShowReminderToUpdate.getCurrentSeason().isPresent()) {
                currentTvShowReminder.setCurrentSeason(tvShowReminderToUpdate.getCurrentSeason().get());
            } else {
                currentTvShowReminder.setCurrentSeason(null);
            }
        }

        if(tvShowReminderToUpdate.getCurrentEpisode() != null) {
            if (tvShowReminderToUpdate.getCurrentEpisode().isPresent()) {
                currentTvShowReminder.setCurrentEpisode(tvShowReminderToUpdate.getCurrentEpisode().get());
            } else {
                currentTvShowReminder.setCurrentEpisode(null);
            }
        }

        if(tvShowReminderToUpdate.getPersonalRating() != null) {
            if (tvShowReminderToUpdate.getPersonalRating().isPresent()) {
                currentTvShowReminder.setPersonalRating(tvShowReminderToUpdate.getPersonalRating().get());
            } else {
                currentTvShowReminder.setPersonalRating(null);
            }
        }

        tvShowReminderRepository.save(currentTvShowReminder);
    }
```

1. I have a question about the @valid annotation in the controller: i thought that it will check if the object that we send from postman for example is of type TvShowReminderPatchDTO , but i can send an entire different object and the controller will start its excecution, and the TvShowReminderPatchDTO will have all its attributes in NULL.

Whats the best way to check if the request body its in fact a TvShowReminderPatchDTO ?
I want to validate if the object we get from the Request is an instance of the TvShowReminderPatchDTO, and if not, throw an Exception.

2. The method that is doing the PATCH is working but its very ugly, I use optional as attributes in the TvShowReminderPatchDTO , so i can distinguish if the client wants to set a NULL (send an attribute with a null value ) or if the attribute was ommited (it does not appear on the request body) so we dont need to do anything, meaning we dont update it.

Can you guys recommend a better way to do this or improve the existing code?

Answer (score 3):

1. Add some required fields using @NotNull annotation in your dto to help Spring understand which attributes should be present in your type
2. Don't use Optional. There is already JsonNullable for this purpose

   public class TvShowReminderPatchDTO
   {
   @NotNull
   private JsonNullable<Boolean> completed = JsonNullable.undefined();
   }

And in controller method:

```
if (dto.getCompleted().isPresent()) {
  object.setCompleted(dto.getCompleted().get());
}
```

That's it, no null-checks required, just set the value

Comment: I saw this today, after a month! I voted your anwser,  now my code has been refactored and working great.
Thank you very much sir!